# Typescript object key as key of another object?

Tags: typescript

I'm creating a generic class like this:

```
type Config = {
  value: string
}
class MyClass<T> {
  configs:{[key in keyof T]: Config },
  data: {[key in keyof T]?: string}

  constructor(configs: { [key in keyof T]: Config }) {
    this.configs = configs;
    this.data= {};
  }

  init() {
    Object.entries(this.configs).forEach(([configName, config]) => {
      if (!(configName in this.data)) {
        this.data[configName] = dosomething(config); // dosomething returns string
      }
    });  
  }
}
```

Then use the class like:

```
const cls = MyClass({
  cfg1: {value: 'value1'},
  cfg2: {value: 'value2'},
})

cls.init();
```

And the `cls.data` is expected to be:

```
{
  cfg1: 'calculated1',
  cfg2: 'calculated2',
}
```

But in the `forEach`, `configName` is `string` and `config` is `unknown`.

I tried `([configName, config]: [key in keyof T, Config]) =>` but that's not working.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the function `Object.entries` is not able to correctly infer the types here. When we look at the type definition of this function it looks like this:

```
entries<T>(o: { [s: string]: T } | ArrayLike<T>): [string, T][];
```

But you are passing an object of type `{ [key in keyof T]: Config }` to the function. TypeScript does not see those as comparable and so the type `[string, unknown][]` is inferred.

---

So how can you solve this?

### Option 1

The easiest way would be to change `{ [key in keyof T]: Config }` to `{ [key : string]: Config }` everywhere.

```js
configs:{[key : string]: Config }
data: {[key : string]: string}

constructor(configs: { [key : string]: Config }) {
  this.configs = configs;
  this.data= {};
}
```

This is essentially identically to the code you had before. You didn't restrain the type `T` to have any particular shape so the keys of `T` could have been any string value anyway. In fact, since we don't use `T` anymore the class does not have to be generic.

Let me know if this works for your specific use case. Or if using `key in keyof T` makes a difference for you.

---

### Option 2

The second option would be to set a constraint on `T`:

```
class MyClass2<T extends Record<string, any>> { /* ... */ }
```

Now TypeScript knows that `keyof T` produces `string` values and the correct types are inferred.

But now we get another error:

```
this.data[configName] = dosomething(config)
// Type 'string' cannot be used to index type '{ [key in keyof T]?: string | undefined; }'
```

This is because `Object.entries` will always return `string` as the first type in the tuple because it is hard-coded in the type definition.

To fix this we have (sadly) to give TypeScript more information:

```
this.data[configName as keyof T] = dosomething(config);
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gOwGYEsDmUC8UDeAoKKANwEMAbAVwgC4oBnYAJxQTTwF888BjMkuulACyIGHwEAeACpQIAD2AQEAE0EAlCNziNlEhs1YAaKCQQgAfOdwEoW5OjrUcAbQDWEEFBZR3IOEigpAF1aeHsMTkJlEmASWhdfLwQfD39AoIB%20Wn0WNE4bO30KbmBtAAo7VDRHXCg3DySUvwDg0MQqqHYASmtCQmAACxQ6ADpKhyxbdocAbht%20odHo2OwcdjnCfMIWFGAynvw%20qAB5ACMAK01gEaUmFAg6MsHhsenqrpGkbQBREm4BsplZzjNAAORIAFsIMYQUEepgrIcjl4AmUAIQVN7gqGNZ5LGIkLoHebIvEjZYkYFYyHQfhNNLBSbKOB0OBQ56sTHhLozKAAej5UGZrPZQ1YUEYEGAFEYCEEOVYJM2JO6vKgNk4%20UKwFsZEE2AQEAA7sJROJHkjuEg0ABGeKkSg0KAAcgdVBtzvYhgK1oATPbyFRaK7AxBfZ7vd0uLxRjs9jygA)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The reason I used `keyof T` is for vscode to correctly recognize the  type and give hints when I type `cls.data.` Option 2 worked for me!